# Assigning attr_accessor using fixtures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures, attr-accessor

I have a simple Rails 3 model, with an attr_accessor that doesn't have a field in the database, and I need to set it up using fixtures, because of my initialization setup.

But when I try it, I get an error about the unknown column.

Is there another way to do this?

My model:

```
class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :interval
    after_initialize :init

    def init
        self.interval ||= 15
        self.start_time ||= Time.local(0, 1, 1)
        self.end_time = self.start_time.advance :minutes => self.interval
    end
end
```

Comment: 1. Why are you using ||= for your initialization?
2. I'm wondering if you're meaning to write `def initialize`...

Comment: @Elland I'm using after_initialize macro because I want to set default values, and hence the ||=. I tried using `def initialize` before, and had a problem, can't remember what was it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures add data directly into the database. If you want to pass data to a model instead, consider using factories ([Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) is a good library).

You may already have a big investment in fixtures, but factories are well worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Fixtures are end state.  Meaning, what's in your database is output after you've called attr_accessor.  So `end_time` would always be calculated for you if you were using it in a test like `@timeslot = timeslots(:your_name_of_fixture)`.  You don't need to worry about them in the Fixture, except for when you are setting it up.

Now, I've not seen an `after_initialize` before, but i see it's a callback function. To me, you are setting an interval in a view. Probably not programmatically (unless it's that default 15 minutes there).

Switching to a `before_save` callback (if you want your people to be able to change intervals on edit too) like:

```
class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :interval
    before_save :set_times
    def set_times
        self.interval ||= 15
        self.start_time ||= Time.local(0, 1, 1)
        self.end_time = self.start_time.advance minutes: self.interval
    end
end
```